# iOS app runs in background and gets notification when a contact is inserted

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, contacts

Is this possible to do? I know basic iOS programming (i've only been playing around with it for a couple weeks), but I was wondering if Apple gives you the ability to do this. I would like the app to receive a notification when a new contact is added and then execute a method from there. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

P.S. I would like the app to not even be running when it gets these notifications too if thats even possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, when a contact is inserted in the device's address book?  No, there's no way to automatically receive a notification triggered by activity in the device's address book.

But with iOS7's added background modes, you could probably take advantage of the Background Fetch mode or Remote Notification mode to regularly check for updates to the user's address book.  Background Fetch is technically supposed to be used to fetch data from a server, but you may be able to use it to fetch address book data in this case… Your app would still have to be running though, albeit in the background.